# How to return the index array of a character in a string in Java

Tags: java

I need to write a method to return the index array of a character in a string in Java. Is the following good (correctness, efficiency, as short code as possible) enough?

```
int[] charIndexArray(String s, char c) {
    int start = 0;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while ((start = s.indexOf(c, start)) != -1) {
        list.add(start);
        start++;
    }
    int arr[] = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
        arr[i] = list.get(i);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Not really, indexOf() return the postion and he is using it.

Comment: Looks like a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the code at the end that copies it to an array with a call to the [toArray() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29). Other than that, looks pretty good.

Comment: Could I get a reason for the -1?

Comment: That's a pretty crappy reason for a -1. Down votes are for inaccurate information, not to show disagreement.

Comment: Here's an objection: the `toArray()` method would return an `Object[]`, and even `toArray(T[])` will return an object array of some kind, which has additional overhead compared to an `int[]`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - good point. I'm not a huge Java coder. I forget that you have to box and unbox so much in Java (granted, C# does it, just automatically, without the coder having to worry about it).

Comment: if so, why you still haven't removed your answer. :)

Comment: What can i say more, crappy answer crappy reason. ;-). Try better next time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
while ((start = s.indexOf(c, start)) != -1) {
    list.add(start);
    start++;
}
```

consider:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
      list.add(i);
    }
 }
```

because the indexOf causes the creation of a whole other loop to search for the next instance of your character.

You code is quietly doing:

```
while (start != -1) {
    start = -1;
    for ( int i=start;i<s.length();i++){
      if ( charAt(i) == c ) {
        start = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    if ( start != -1 ) { 
    list.add(start);
    start++;
  }
}
```

Which does not seem more efficient. But it turns out that after spending way too much time on this:

```
static int[] charIndexArrayByBits(String s, char c) {
    int start = 0;
    int[] list = new int[s.length()];
    int count = -1;
    while ((start = s.indexOf(c, start)) != -1) {
      list[++count] = start;
      start++;
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(list, count);
  }
```

is faster.  But I would not consider it more efficient in the general case because you are allocating an int array which would be larger space wise.

Comment: but the overall iteration length is the same, i believe, in both cases, of course, if one can safely assume Java String is random-accessible sequence container.

Comment: Do not forget about the boxing invoved.

Comment: right, my original solution still loop over the string once! The only place where it can be made "more" (no matter how small) efficiently is to remove the boxing/unboxing part, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The code do not look good.

You use two loop instead of one.

Try to use methods.

charAt(int pos) for string and Arrays.copy

The OP shold not read more ;p

The first is the location this kind of method should be placed in some util class and be static IMHO.

```
public class CharSequenceUtil {

    private static int[] EMPTY_INT_ARRAY = new int[0];

    /**
    * Method search the position of given character in char sequence.
    *
    * @param CharSequence seq - Sequence of char that will be investigate 
    * @param char c - Character that is analysed.
    *
    * @return int array with positions of char c in CharSequence instanace
    * @throws NullPointerException if seq is null.
    */
    public static int[] charIndexArray(CharSequence seq, char c) {

      if(seq == null) {
        throw new NullPointerExcetion("The seq must not be null");
      }

      if(seq.length() == 0) {
        return EMPTY_INT_ARRAY;
      }

      int[] positions = new int[seq.lenth()];
      int stor = -1; 

      for(int pos = 0; pos < seq.length(); seq++) {
         if(c == seq.charAt(pos)) {
          positions[++stor] = pos;
         }
      }

      if(stor == -1) {
        return EMPTY_INT_ARRAY;
      }

      return Arrays.copyOf(positions, stor);
    }
}
```

Comment: how so about two loops? i only see one iteration over the string.

Comment: @QiangLi, in the indexOf you have another loop and additioanl you call a method that is not really designed for this usage. It should be used when you are insterted in position and you do not want to write the whole code.

Comment: I think that this is the more faster way. I don't know if `System.arrayCopy` is more faster because is native method.

Comment: The copyOf, call System.arrayCopy, so that is the gain.